# Make sure two functions in different files run in the correct order?

Tags: javascript

So I have two functions in different files.

File 1 looks like this:

```js
function 1() {
    do something
}
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    1();
});
```

and file two looks like:

```js
function 2() {
    do something
}
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    2();
});
```

I want function 1 to run before function 2.
Currently I do this by importing them like this;

```html
<head>
   <script src="file1">
   <script src="file2">
</head>
```

The problem with this is it is quite fragile as if someone where to switch the imports then it would stop working, so I am asking if there is a better way of doing it to ensure that function 1 will be run before function 2(and no I can't put them in the same file).

Comment: Call function 2 from function 1.

Comment: Fix your design. It's perfectly reasonable to have your functions defined in separate files, but it doesn't make sense to also add your DOM event listeners in those files if you want to have a defined order. You need one event listener that calls both functions in sequence.

Comment: Call the sequence of two `window.addEventListener`s from your page after you've imported the files, instead of in the individual files?

Comment: "*I want function 1 to run before function 2*" - why do you care? As written, these functions are totally independent, and order should not matter.

Comment: `<!-- The order of the following scripts matters! -->`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the event listeners from the JS files and wire up the events in the html file.

```html
<head>
  <script src="file1">
  <script src="file2">

  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    1()
    2()
  });
</head>
```

Better yet, load up the scripts at the end of the `<body>` which will help with faster load times of the raw html.

```html
<head>
<!-- not much here -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- html -->

  <script src="file1">
  <script src="file2">

  <script>
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      1()
      2()
    });
  </script>
</body>
```